# Sharing the metrics in cache of two nodes within a graphite cluster

Tags: monitoring, graphite, graphite-carbon

I have a graphite cluster with 2 nodes under and ELB. Both of them share a same NFS to store the metrics.I didn't have a problem in accessing the metrics that are already written to the NFS.The problem arises in the case where node 1 have some metrics in its cache and have not written yet to the NFS and node 2 tries to access that metric.So one solution that I have in mind is to include the IP of both servers in local_setting.py

```
#########################
# Cluster Configuration #
#########################
#CLUSTER_SERVERS = ["10.x.x.1:80", "10.x.x.2:80"]
```

Is there any other way or a better solution to access the cache in node 1 from node 2 under the same ELB ?

Answer (score 1):

Graphite is using files on the disk for resolving globs (e.g. '*') in metric names. If the metric is not yet written to disk - it will not be visible in Graphite.
Adding `CLUSTER_SERVERS` will not help because they should be another `graphite-web` instances and not caches. You can add both caches to `CARBONLINK_HOSTS`, i.e.

`CARBONLINK_HOSTS = [‘10.x.x.1:7002’,‘10.x.x.2:7002’]`

but I doubt that helps because of what I said above.

Comment: the nodes, node 1 and node 2, have graphite-web installed on it. They have a common whisper db location. In this case will CLUSTER_SERVERS help ?

Comment: Yes, maybe I mixed up two issues, sorry for that. Not sure about detail of your problem. You can try both -  if you have graphite-web installed, of course.

Comment: Yeah it worked! Also is there a general way of having fault tolerance in graphite? In my case the only reason to add an additional node is to make the dashboard available even if one node goes offline. How can we achieve fault tolerance in graphite generally. Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: If NFS is working for you - why not, keep it like that. But usually, NFS starts to choke under increasing load very soon.

Comment: Sorry, pressed Enter by mistake.
Graphite has replication - you need to install relay with replication factor = 2, so, duplicate metrics on two graphite instances, which you can connect to each other using  CLUSTER_SERVERS. But in that case you need to sync data after possible outages, so, if NFS works - keep it like that.